# How can I display the object array in 2 columns Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

```
var match1 = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"];

  var match2 = [
  {
  "drop":"Drop1",
  "definition": "This is the definition1"
  }, 
  {
  "drop":"Drop2",
  "definition": "This is the definition2"
  },
  {
  "drop":"Drop3",
  "definition": "This is the definition3"
  },
  {
  "drop":"Drop4",
  "definition": "This is the definition4"
  },
  {
  "drop":"Drop5",
  "definition": "This is the definition5"
  },
  {
  "drop":"Drop6",
  "definition": "This is the definition6"
  },
  {
  "drop":"Drop7",
  "definition": "This is the definition7"
  },
  {
  "drop":"Drop8",
  "definition": "This is the definition8"
  },
  {
  "drop":"Drop9",
  "definition": "This is the definition9"
  },
  {
  "drop":"Drop10",
  "definition": "This is the definition10"
  },
   ];
```

How can I display the Object array in 2 different columns? Thank you.

https://jsfiddle.net/eqf3tcx2/16/

Comment: How about: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/eqf3tcx2/19/

Comment: The drop should shuffle too with the definition. Drop1 ==== Definition 1 should shuffle together, Thank you for your help.

Comment: I was able to solve it: https://jsfiddle.net/eqf3tcx2/21/

Comment: Nice, I added it as an answer, then. With some explanation on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a column. To get the properties from the objects, use `match2[i].drop` and `match2[i].definition`.

See step by step for a suggested solution:

- Add the column.

  - This:

    ```
    <div id="column" class="definition">
      <h3>Definition</h3>
    </div>
    ```
  - Should become:

    ```
    <div id="column" class="definition">
      <h3>Definition</h3>
      <br>              
      <ul id="defs"></ul>
    </div>
    ```
- Create an array to hold the new column's values, add `.data` properties to the second column and `.description` properties to the third, newly created, column.

  - This:

    ```
    var arrMatch2 = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < match2.length; i++) {
      arrMatch2.push('<li data-index="' + (i + 1) + '">' + match2[i] + '</li>');
    }
    ```
  - Should become:

    ```
    var arrMatch2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < match2.length; i++) {
      arrMatch2.push('<li data-index="' + (i + 1) + '">' + match2[i].drop + '</li>');
    }

    var arrMatch3 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < match2.length; i++) {
      arrMatch3.push('<li data-index="' + (i + 1) + '">' + match2[i].definition + '</li>');
    }
    ```
- Finally, shuffle the array and add it to the column.

  - This:

    ```
    var arrMatch2 = [];
    //shuffle the arrays
    arrMatch1 = shuffle(arrMatch1);
    arrMatch2 = shuffle(arrMatch2);

    //insert them into DOM
    $('#source').html(arrMatch1.join(''));
    $('#target').html(arrMatch2.join(''));
    ```
  - Should become:

    ```
    //shuffle the arrays
    arrMatch1 = shuffle(arrMatch1);
    arrMatch2 = shuffle(arrMatch2);
    arrMatch3 = shuffle(arrMatch2);

    //insert them into DOM
    $('#source').html(arrMatch1.join(''));
    $('#target').html(arrMatch2.join(''));
    $('#defs').html(arrMatch3.join(''));
    ```

[Suggested JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/eqf3tcx2/32/).

## Shuffling `drop`/`definition` columns together

The simplest solution is to shuffle the `match2` source array before generating the two product arrays (`arrMatch2` and `arrMatch3`), instead of generating the two product arrays and shuffling them:

```
var arrMatch1 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < match1.length; i++) {
  arrMatch1.push('<li data-index="' + (i + 1) + '">' + match1[i] + '</li>');
}
//shuffle the arrays
arrMatch1 = shuffle(arrMatch1);
//insert them into DOM
$('#source').html(arrMatch1.join(''));

// clone and shuffle the array
var match2Clone = $.map(match2, function (m, i) { return {drop: m.drop, definition: m.definition, id: i}; });
var shuffledMatch2 = shuffle(match2Clone);
var arrMatch2 = [], arrMatch3 = [];
for (var ism = 0; ism < shuffledMatch2.length; ism++) {
  var m = shuffledMatch2[ism];
  arrMatch2.push('<li data-index="' + (m.id + 1) + '">' + m.drop + '</li>');
  arrMatch3.push('<li data-index="' + (m.id + 1) + '">' + m.definition + '</li>');
}
//insert them into DOM
$('#target').html(arrMatch2.join(''));
$('#defs').html(arrMatch3.join(''));
```

[**Updated Demo JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/eqf3tcx2/47/).

Comment: Just another question: how can I shuffle the drop zone and definitions together? Looks like they don't shuffle together.

Comment: What do you mean by shuffle together?

Comment: #target and #defs should shuffle at the same number eg: drop1 === Definition1

Comment: Do you still need it?

Comment: This is what Im aiming for but it is not accepting all the draggables now. https://jsfiddle.net/eqf3tcx2/40/

Comment: I have updated the answer (new JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/eqf3tcx2/47/)

Comment: Did you try the updated answer? Oh, and since you are a new user, just FIY: meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/219205 if the answer helped, of course.

Comment: Oh, then, can you mark it as accepted so we know it is answered? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/219205